# Can't run node.js server

Tags: node.js

Using macOs High Sierra, trying to run small node.js code, from iTerm, showing this error:

```
module.js:545

        throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module '/Users/vikasenkova/server.js'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:470:25)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:690:10)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:194:16)
        at bootstrap_node.js:666:3
```

Cant't find solution here.. if somebody knows.. when trying to delete files with this: `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
showing that permission denied.

Comment: Not following but to address the second point, have you tried `sudo rm -rf` since it looks like you may have used npm as root? i.e, `sudo npm install`

Comment: Why are you trying to delete the `node_modules` folder?

Comment: Also: post the code that launches your server.

Comment: i'm trying to delete, cuz i found this [link](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689) thought that it will help. `node server.js` with that I tried to launch the server.

Comment: Do you have a file in the current directory named `server.js`? If not, that's your problem.